# FormatException calculating the sum of a column in a ListView

Tags: c#

I have a problem in my `listview` that I can't calculate the summation of a specific column.

In my project, I am reading an bit of information from an excel-file to the `ListView`, then processing this information by doing some of the operations.

Now when I am reading the information to the `ListView` I can't calculate the summation of a specific column, the function is:-

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int iSum = 0;
    foreach (ListViewItem o in this.lsvMain.Items )
    {
        iSum = iSum + Convert.ToInt16(o.SubItems[8].Text);
        textBox1.Text = iSum.ToString();
    }
```

The error message appears: **FormatException was unhandled (input string was not in the correct format).** it's indicating to the (iSum..) line.

There isn't any string all the information are integer!

Comment: Do you have an example of the strings passed to `Convert.ToInt16`? Are you sure that the numbers are small enough to fit in an `int16`? What happens if you use `Convert.ToInt32` instead?

Comment: Maybe there is a space in the string, have you tried trimming them first?

Comment: (attach the debugger and give some more details plx)

Comment: Why are you converting to int16 when you are summing an int? Also shouldn't you be setting textBox1.Text outside of the loop?

Comment: Learn how to set variables / values inside a loop, why are you overwriting the same variable in the loop set that outside the loop. here is a great site where you can learn how to code the basics http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;

    foreach (ListViewItem o in lsvMain.Items)
    {
        int value;
        if (int.TryParse(o.SubItems[8].Text, out value))
            sum += value;
    }

    textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that error when you are trying to `Parse` (or `Convert`) something to an `Integer`, which is just not an `Integer`.

e.g.

```
var anIntegerValue = Convert.ToInt16("a");
```

will result with an exception:

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Attach the debugger to your program and check what you are retrieving as value from your listbox. It will surprise you :).

The proposed example from Daniel will result in the same problem. `int.Parse()` or `Int32.Parse` or `Convert.Int16` or `Convert.Int32` will all result in the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have one of these problems:

```
int aNumber = Convert.ToInt16("15.6"); //throws format exception because of decimal value
int anotherNumber = Convert.ToInt16(""); //throws format exception because there is nothing to convert
int yetAnotherNumber = Convert.ToInt16("-23.00"); //throws format exception because of .00
```

I'm guessing you are reading the numbers in excel file and keeping their string representation.

If the column is formated as number, i'm guessing all numbers are represented as "X.00" or similar and thus, causing your **FormatException**